# Unable to connect to a PostgreSQL database

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I've been accessing a PostGIS database in QGIS I created on an old laptop and now trying to reconnect to it with a new laptop. I've installed PostgreSQL 14 whilst the database I want to connect to was created with a PostgreSQL 11 install (unsure if this matters).

In pgAdmin 6.5, I exported all servers from the old laptop and imported them (.json) in pgAdmin on the new one. The databases I created on the old laptop haven't imported and wonder if this is due to the hosting configuration of the database.

The database of interest is called ***Inspire Data***; host name, ***localhost***; port ***5433***; maintenance database, ***postgres***; username, ***postgres***

I attempted connecting to the database in QGIS by importing an export (.xml) of databases from the old laptop which added some remotely hosted db's but not the one of interest. If trying to add manually, QGIS claims the password authentication failed for user 'postgres'.

I am new to PostGIS etc and no doubt naive if I thought I could connect to the old database that might only be accessible on the old laptop because of the host being 'local'.

Comment: 1) If you want to transfer the data between computers, you must dump and load the data. Have a look at [pg_dumpall](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-dumpall.html).

Comment: 2) If you want the data to stay on the old server and to connect to it, you must configure the old server to allow connections from your new computer (by IP or else) and you must connect using the server IP or name.